# Alerts not opening from if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

I am making a rock paper scissors game, and I want alerts to determine who picked what and who won, but the alerts dont pop up. I found multiple errors going back and fixed them, double checked everything, and even gave a triple check, but the alerts still do not pop up?

This is one of the three functions (they all are similar):

```
function rock() {
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }
}
if (computerChoice === "rock") {
   alert("Link and Computer both chose Rock! It's a Tie!");
} else if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
   alert("Link chose Rock and Computer chose Scissors! Computer took a heart of damage!");
} else {
   alert("Link chose Rock and Computer chose Paper! Link took a heart of damage!");
}
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in you Javascript console in your browser. For example, for Chrome open it using F12 on Windows or alt-cmd-I on OS X, go to Sources tab. Locate first line of your function, click on the left edge (where line numbers are) to set a break point, and trigger your function.

Comment: When I reformatted your code, it because obvious there was a syntax error in it .. an extra `}` at the end.

Always make sure that you check your error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is on the line indicated:

```
function rock() {
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }
} // <-- I don't think you want this closing brace here
if (computerChoice === "rock") {
   alert("Link and Computer both chose Rock! It's a Tie!");
} else if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
   alert("Link chose Rock and Computer chose Scissors! Computer took a heart of damage!");
} else {
   alert("Link chose Rock and Computer chose Paper! Link took a heart of damage!");
}
}
```

The closing brace I've indicated brings an end to the `rock()` function.  As it stands, the `rock()` function doesn't actually do anything; it assigns a value `"rock"`, `"paper"` or `"scissors"` at random to a local variable, but the function ends without the variable being used, so the value is lost.

The rest of the code is then run once when the JavaScript is first loaded into the browser.  At this point, `computerChoice` will be `undefined`, and hence you will get a JavaScript error.

If we remove the errant brace, and reformat the code, we get the following:

```
function rock() {
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }

  if (computerChoice === "rock") {
     alert("Link and Computer both chose Rock! It's a Tie!");
  } else if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
     alert("Link chose Rock and Computer chose Scissors! Computer took a heart of damage!");
  } else {
     alert("Link chose Rock and Computer chose Paper! Link took a heart of damage!");
  }
}
```

I ran this function several times.  Each time it alerted one of the three messages at random.

Comment: That sure did it! I took the time to read your entire response, to make sure I was doing it right, and your explanation kind of wanted me to face palm myself. I should really look thoroughly to see what I typed up. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an alert. Alert is a method call. Remove the return in front of the alert, and the alert will open:

```
if(computerChoice === "rock"){
    alert("Link and Computer both chose Rock! It's a Tie!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful tip, I will have to remember that in the future. Sadly, I removed the return statements, but it still didn't give me an alert message. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the return. So, change this:

```
if(computerChoice === "rock"){
  return alert("Link and Computer both chose Rock! It's a Tie!");
}
```

to this:

```
if(computerChoice === "rock"){
  alert("Link and Computer both chose Rock! It's a Tie!");
}
```

Comment: I removed the return statements like you said, but it still didn't give me an alert message. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

This works and uses less detours to get there :)

```
function rock() {
  var replies = new Array(
    'Link and Computer both chose Rock! It\'s a Tie!',
    'Link chose Rock and Computer chose Scissors! Computer took a heart of damage!',
    'Link chose Rock and Computer chose Paper! Link took a heart of damage!');
  alert(replies[Math.floor(replies.length * Math.random())]);
}
```

Clarification:
Math.random() returns a float in the range [0..1>
replies.length * Math.random() returns a float in the range [0..3>
Math.floor(replies.length * Math.random()) returns 0, 1 or 2.